# Looking to create tooltip fof headers on jsgrid

Tags: tooltip, jsgrid

As I am using jsgrid. I am looking for support to create tooltip for few headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `headerTemplate` of the field setting `title` attribute of the wrapping div:

```
headerTemplate: function() { 
    return $("<div>")
               .prop("title", "My Tooltip")
               .text(this.title); 
}
```

Look at the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/uyn8mwjg/